How can I use Outlook reminders more effectively?
I am extremely dependent on Outlook reminders to meet my professional commitments.
My standard workflow is:

send email

right click the follow-up flag

click add reminder

select date and time


I probably send around 50 emails a day, and need to set reminders on about half of those, going out weeks or even months.
This workflow is very brittle. Some issues include, for example:

I may send an email and get distracted. No reminder gets set.

Accidental dismissing of reminders is easy and can result in a reminder being simply lost.

Accidental snoozing is easy, although just introduces delays.

No custom snooze durations.

Task list is permanently cluttered with reminders and follow-up flags, and basically unusable for, you know, tracking tasks.


Are there any better, more stable, less brittle approaches to this workflow? The first two issues, in particular, are pretty serious to me in the sense that they can cause me forget deadlines, etc. In fact this happens all the time.
Alternatively, are there any alternatives to Outlook reminders (e.g., Outlook add-ins or other Outlook features)?
Using Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2405 Build 16.0.17628.20006) 32-bit, whatever that means.


You can create a Quick Step that flags an email for follow-up and sets a reminder with just one click.
Consider using Rules to automatically flag emails from specific senders or with certain keywords.

